# PHP Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found in /MyApp/chat-server.php

Tags: php, composer-php, ratchet

I am trying to run the Ratchet application demo but I can't execute the file

This is my file structure

```
/var/www/src/MyApp/
/var/www/src/MyApp/chat.php
/var/www/src/MyApp/chat-server.php
```

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

#require "chat.php";

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new Chat(),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
```

```
/var/www/src/MyApp/composer.json
```

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/Ratchet": "0.3.*"
    }
}
```

Vendor Folder is exist in this location

```
/var/www/src/MyApp/vendor/
```

Whenever I am executing the chat-server file in terminal I got the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found in /MyApp/chat-server.php
```

**Please help me how to resolve this**

*Note:* The complete code details are exist in this page

http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

This question was asked but still no answer for that question too
[Class 'MyChat\Chat' not found in C:\wamp\www\bin\chat-server.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172707/class-mychat-chat-not-found-in-c-wamp-www-bin-chat-server-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main path for the autoloading is the location of the composer.json file, so if that lives in `/var/www/src/MyApp/`, the autoloading will use that as a base.

In your case, you say the `MyApp` namespace can be found in the `src` directory (which means `/var/www/src/MyApp/src`). That's not true, since the file `/var/www/src/MyApp/src/MyApp/Chat.php` does not exists.

You can solve this issue in 3 different ways:

- **Moving `composer.json`** - You can move the `composer.json` file to `/var/www`, to be able to use that as base;
- **Updating autoloading** (using PSR-4) - You can also use PSR-4 instead of PSR-0 and configure it as `"autoload": { "psr-4": { "MyApp\\": "" } }`;
- **Reorganizing your files** - You can also change the file structure to:

  ```
  /var/www/src/MyApp/
      src/MyApp/
              Chat.php
      composer.json
  ```

Answer (score 19):

If you don't have the composer.json file and the vendor folder at root, it won't work. Also, don't touch the vendor folder (and subfolders). The folder structure must be like this:

```
/composer.json
/composer.phar
/vendor/[misc]
/src/MyApp/Chat.php
```

Finally, after updating the composer.json, make sure to run an update:

```
php composer.phar update
```

This way it will work.

Comment: the tutorial didn't say to run the update command after updating the json file. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

You have to mention Base Path of your classes that need to be autoloaded:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src/MyApp/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.0",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*"
    }
}
```

And run

> Composer dump-autoload

Comment: Composer dump-autoload is what worked for me, this stuff always change, now it is the version 0.4.1 of ratchet.

Comment: Thank you so much! I almost give up since I did follow exactly as Ratchet tutorial and some guy youtube and still got this error. Do I need to run "Composer dump-autoload" each time I change composer.json?

Answer (score 8):

Try autoloading the files first with:

```
$ composer update
```

If it still doesn't work then include the line `require 'chat.php';`, just at the beginning of the `chat-server.php` file. It worked for me.

Comment: `composer update` does not cause any autoloading.

Comment: @NicoHaase, it does if you have "autoload" key in your composer.json file. I just tried it and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working configuration:

```
root
├── bin
│   └── chat-server.php
├── src
│   └── Chat.php
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
└── vendor
```

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4"
    }
}
```

The tutorial does not mention that after adding/updating the `autoload` section in *composer.json* you need to run a `composer install` to **regenerate autoload files**.

Answer (score 1):

I wrestled with this issue for hours and found that I was missing a few packages. I was able to fix it with this command:

```
php composer.phar install --no-dev -o
```

Here's a picture of what I saw after running:
[installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsVL4.png)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after spending half a day, I realised the error was because I missed this line:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```