# NameScape Error. Stuck in 'MyApp\Chat'

Tags: php, composer-php, ratchet

Getting Error in Ratchet Simple Example:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found`

My File Structure is like:

```
root\composer.json 
root\bin\chat-server.php 
root\src\MyApp\Chat.php
```

Composer.json is

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*"
    }
}
```

chat-server.php is

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new Chat(),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
```

and Chat.php is

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

I have tried following, but still now works:
[PHP Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found in /MyApp/chat-server.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012574/php-fatal-error-class-myapp-chat-not-found-in-myapp-chat-server-php)

Comment: Can you do `print_r(get_declared_classes());` and see if it's being loaded under a different namespace?

Comment: Did you tried composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your autoload naming https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0

It should be like that:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*"
    }
}
```

And do

```
composer dump-autoload
```